# Is it possible to keep a reference as a class member in C++? Please give an example

Tags: c++, reference

As far as I know, References need to be declared and initialized at the same time.

I guess, its only use lies in passing arguments and in some cases Polymorphism.

Is it possible to keep a reference as a data member in a class?

If yes, when should we need that?

Please give me an example.

Comment: A quick googling turned this up: http://www.goingware.com/tips/parameters/refmembers.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would use a reference as a class member when it is an integral part of the class, without which the class cannot function, and you want to either share this part among several classes or use it polymorphically:

```
class Presenter
{
    IView & view;
    IModel & model;

    Presenter(IView & view, IModel & model)
        : view(view), model(model)
    {
    }
};
```

A reference member cannot be changed after construction, so using one makes a strong statement about how the class is meant to be used. Using regular or smart pointers offers more flexibility.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* have reference-type data members, but as a general rule you *should not* declare reference-type data members.  A class with a reference-type data member is not assignable (because references are not assignable); this greatly restricts the use of the class.

It's almost always preferable to use pointer-type data members, since they effectively provide the same capabilities, with the same lifetime constraints, but without making the class not assignable.

Comment: There's nothing stopping someone from writing an `operator=` for a class with a reference-type data member. You just can't set the reference member in that assignment operator. Sometimes this makes sense, sometimes it doesn't. It depends very much on the class and what that reference member is intended to mean.

Comment: @DavidHammen:  I am interested to know:  under what circumstances is such a data member useful?

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: They are useful as data members when the referenced object must exist throughout the lifetime of the containing object (construction to destruction) and when the semantics of the containing object dictates that the referenced object must never change during the lifetime of the object. Const data members are occasionally useful, as are pointer members. A reference member is a essentially a pointer const member that is guaranteed to be non-null.

Comment: @DavidHammen:  I maintain my argument then that reference-type data members are not useful (and, for what it's worth, that const-qualified data members are also not useful).  Constness of data and immutability of reference can (and should) be enforced by policy, or if one really insists, through the use of a class template (e.g. a simple `const_data<T>`, or `non_null<T>`, or `faux_reference<T>`).   Reference data members are simply not worth the trouble.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis There's nothing wrong with a non-assignable class.  Not every class can be made that way, of course, but there are tons of classes that can.
Reference members really are useful, as they provide a little extra safety (an _enforced_ constraint is always preferable to "policy" constraint), and a more readable notation.

Comment: @snogglethorpe:  There's nothing wrong with a class that is noncopyable (or even nonmovable, though nonmovable types are few and far between).  There is, however, something very fishy about a type that is copy-constructible but not copy-assignable (or even move-constructible but not move-assignable):  it generally indicates that the author of the class made poor implementation decisions or didn't know what he was doing.  It is trivial to write a template to enforce the initialization-and-not-null constraint, and such code is just as readable (if not moreso).

Comment: @JamesMcNellis Copy-construction was not mentioned (though there's _also_ nothing wrong with copy-c'table but not assignable types).  You seem to be making the mistake of thinking that every class should be perfectly general, and usable in any context, but DavidHammen's point was spot on: different types of classes, intended to be used in different circumstances, can have different constraints.
Anyway, this all comes down to taste; there's nothing wrong with your personal style rules, but I want to make the point to any readers that they _are_ somewhat arbitrary, and not universally held.

Answer (score 0):

As don has pointed out a reference member can be used in much the same way as a pointer member. I think it is worth pointing out though that pointers can also be null and also be reseated so are much more useful in most respects.

additionally, in modern C++ you probably wouldn't use a pointer or reference member as you can use [shared_ptr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982026.aspx) or [unique_ptr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee410601.aspx) to better encapsulate the lifetime of the members